# How to retrieve data sent via xhr.send()?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a form with two input fields, text and a file. I am able to get the form data. But what I am struggling to do is to retrieve the form data on the file that I posted the data to.

My Code is as follows:

```
   function addAnswer() {
         //   var currentUser = 2;

            var formData = new FormData();


            //Get comments    
            var comments = document.getElementById("res_comm").value;

             if (comments.length < 1) {
                 alert("Please input some commetns"); 
            }

            //Get picture from form
            var logo = document.getElementById('res_files');


                 //Check if theres a comment
                if (logo.files.length > 0) {
                    formData.append("res_files", logo.files[0]);
                    exit();
                }


                formData.append("comments", comments);
                formData.append("update_id", UpdateID);

            console.log(...formData);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST',  './nonconfirmitys/savedata.json', true);      
            xhr.send(formData);
    //location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you call send, trap one of the events of `xhr`.  `onreadystatechange` is cross-browser compatible, but has more code involved.  `onload` is likely a good candidate.  Once it's loaded, there are many properties of `xhr` to see what came back from the server.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

OK, After some research, I managed to solve the problem. the code is as follows:

```
 public function savedata()
        {
          $this->autoRender = false;
          $this->response->type('json');
          $json = json_encode(array('message'=>'Input some stuff here!'));
          $this->response->body($json);          
          //var_dump($this->request->data);

                $comments = $_POST['comments'];
                $id = $_POST['update_id'];
                $currentUser = $this->Auth->user();
                $this->request->data['usr_id'] = $currentUser['User']['usr_id'];

        if (!empty($_FILES)) {

            $file = $_FILES['res_files'];

            $rawFilename = explode('.', $file['name']);
            $originalextention = $rawFilename[count($rawFilename)-1];
            $filename = md5('picture'.time()).'.'.$originalextention;
            $newName = $filename;
        }
        else{
            $filename= "";
        }
        if (empty($newName)) {
                $this->set('errors', $this->jsonResponse('FAL', 'File not uploaded, Please try again'));
                return $this->set('_serialize', 'errors');
        }

         if (!empty($_FILES)) {
                $file = $_FILES['res_files'];
                $uploadDir = WWW_ROOT . DS . 'files' . DS;
                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadDir.$filename);
           }


            $this->loadModel('Nonconfirmity');
            $this->Nonconfirmity->read(null, $id);
            $this->Nonconfirmity->set('res_comments', $comments);
            $this->Nonconfirmity->set('res_user_id', $this->request->data['usr_id']);
            $this->Nonconfirmity->set('res_files', $filename);
            $this->Nonconfirmity->set('res_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $this->Nonconfirmity->set('res_status', "Solved");
            $this->Nonconfirmity->save();

            $this->Nonconfirmity->save();
```

}